# Why i am getting SolrException and TimeoutException then Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:6511 within 10000 ms

Tags: apache-zookeeper, liferay-6, solr4

i am trying to connect from application layer to solr search layer i get this 
  error in liferay log file, could you please help me on this
   ## Heading ##List item

> 00:00:06,363 ERROR
>   [liferay/search_writer/SYSTEM_ENGINE-5][SolrIndexWriter:134] Max
>   delete retries reached (uid 15_PORTLET_46713_FIELD_59339731)
>       org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper
>   localhost:6511 within 10000 ms
>         at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.(SolrZkClient.java:148)
>         at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.(SolrZkClient.java:99)
>         at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.(SolrZkClient.java:89)
>         at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.(ZkStateReader.java:195)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.connect(CloudSolrServer.java:240)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer.request(CloudSolrServer.java:501)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:118)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.deleteById(SolrServer.java:239)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.deleteById(SolrServer.java:225)
>         at com.liferay.portal.search.solr.SolrIndexWriter.deleteDocument(SolrIndexWriter.java:122)
>         at com.liferay.portal.search.solr.SolrIndexWriter.updateDocument(SolrIndexWriter.java:241)
>         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor362.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.MethodHandler.invoke(MethodHandler.java:83)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyRequest.execute(ProxyRequest.java:57)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyMessageListener.receive(ProxyMessageListener.java:51)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:72)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:69)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:678)
>         at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:589)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:6511 within 10000 ms
>         at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager.waitForConnected(ConnectionManager.java:223)
>         at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.(SolrZkClient.java:140)
>         ... 21 more

Comment: Please add more information than just the error message: What's the code in question? What did you configure? And make extra extra *extra* sure that you have something running on localhost:6511 (where localhost is the server that Liferay is running on)

Comment: solar plugin is configured in one server(application layer) and the solar and zookeeper is placed on  other server(search layer) ,i run playbook its  up to deployment on webapss folder is working ,next it's failed to connect with solar and zk (but solr, zk  is  alive)

Comment: “other server“ or “localhost“?